# Java-Assigning an Action Listener to a JMenuItem, cannot figure out what's wrong

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement some actionListeners to my JMenuItems in order to get them working. Ideally I've created:

```
public class BearFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

   private JFrame frame;
   private JLabel label;   
   private JMenuItem Interface;
   private JMenuItem sql; 

   public BearFrame() {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("BearHouse Management System");
        
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        
        /**
         *
         * @file-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         */
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(file);
        
        JMenuItem Interface = new JMenuItem("Interface Options");
        file.add(Interface);
        Interface.addActionListener(this);
        Interface.setToolTipText("Edit your personal UI preferences");
        
        
        JMenuItem sql = new JMenuItem("SQL Operations");
        file.add(sql);
        sql.addActionListener(this);
        sql.setToolTipText("Import Database/Edit");

        frame.setVisible(true);
        
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(ae.getSource() == Interface) {
        
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
    else if(ae.getSource()==sql){
        System.out.println("Test1");    
    }
        System.out.println("Error");
}
```

The problem is that whenever I get to run the program, the console just prints the "Error" message, even though I click on the correct JMenuItems.
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si3OC.png)

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.
**Note**: This is not the full program but I think it covers exactly the points needed to determine whether I lost something on the way.

Comment: `JMenuItem Interface = new JMenuItem("Interface Options");` <- Doing this inside a method will create a local variable. This local variable will be different from the field you declared at class level and are using in the actionPerformed method. If you instead want to instantiate your already existing field remove the type at the beginning: `Interface = new JMenuItem("Interface Options");`. Same for your other field/local variable.

Comment: Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of your variable names are correct others are not. Be consistent and follow Java naming conventions.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, but thankfully in java i cannot declare a variable with value ="interface" because interface is brought by the default library, that's the only reason that I renamed it to "Interface".

Comment: Call it something else then, for example interfaceMenuItem.

Comment: The message "Error" is produced on every invocation of the `actionPerformed` method - it does not actually indicate an error has occurred.  I would strongly suggest that you create a separate ActionListener for each component rather than trying to have your parent object (i.e. BearFrame) manage all of the behaviors.